# Trigger on task - only for certian profiles

Tags: trigger

I have created this trigger to update a date field on the opportunity when a task is edited. I need it to only fire if the user has a certain profile. I can get this to work if I list out each users id, but not by profile. can someone answer why this is not working? What am I missing?

```
trigger LastRAETaskDate on Task (after insert, after update) {

    // set up lists you will need
    datetime myDate = datetime.now();
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();
    String Profile = userinfo.getProfileId();



    // go through the list of tasks that were inserted
    for (Task t: Trigger.New)
    {
        // if they are related to a contact, add the contact id (whoID) and their values to a map
        if (t.WhatId  != null & Profile == '00ea000000221Ng' )
        {
            taskMap.put(t.WhatId, t);
        }
    }

    // if the map isnt empty
    if (taskMap.size() > 0)
    {
        // get all of the contacts related to the tasks
        oppsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Last_RAE_Update__c FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN: taskMap.keySet()];
        // go through the list for each opportunity
        for (Opportunity o: oppsToUpdate)
        {
            // set the RAE update field to the date
            o.Last_RAE_Update__c = myDate;
        }

        // if the list of opps isnt empty, update them
        if (oppsToUpdate.size() > 0)
        {
            update oppsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick first fix is to change "& Profile" to "&& Profile".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error I can  find is in this line:

```
if (t.WhatId  != null & Profile == '00ea000000221Ng' )
```

The AND should have two &'s:

```
if (t.WhatId  != null && Profile == '00ea000000221Ng' )
```

Everything else looks good.  For debugging, use some `System.debug()` statements to see what the Trigger is actually doing at Runtime.

---

```
trigger LastRAETaskDate on Task (after insert, after update) {

    // set up lists you will need
    datetime myDate = datetime.now();
    List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id, Task> taskMap = new Map<Id, Task>();
    String Profile = userinfo.getProfileId();
    system.debug('User ProfileId = '+Profile);
    system.debug('Required ProfileId = 00ea000000221Ng');

    // go through the list of tasks that were inserted
    for (Task t: Trigger.New){
        // if they are related to a contact, add the contact id (whoID) and their values to a map
        if (t.WhatId  != null && Profile == '00ea000000221Ng' ){
            taskMap.put(t.WhatId, t);
        }
    }

    // if the map isnt empty  
    // *** saying !taskMap.isEmpty() costs much less than using taskMap.size()>0  ***
    system.debug('taskMap = '+taskMap);
    if (!taskMap.isEmpty())  {
        // get all of the contacts related to the tasks
        oppsToUpdate = [SELECT Id, Last_RAE_Update__c 
                        FROM Opportunity 
                        WHERE Id IN: taskMap.keySet()];
        // go through the list for each opportunity
        for (Opportunity o: oppsToUpdate){
            // set the RAE update field to the date
            o.Last_RAE_Update__c = myDate;
        }

        // if the list of opps isnt empty, update them
        system.debug('oppsToUpdate = '+oppsToUpdate);
        if (!oppsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            update oppsToUpdate;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That did it. I knew it had to be simple!